# why icons not showing in my buttons jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I work in a mobile website and now try make back buttons with icons, my button work well but my problem is I add a jquery mobile icon to my button and not showing below I let my code, I cannot see what is the problem, I use a custom theme that develop with theme roller works well try put the images folder that download with my theme in the jquery folder where are the css, structure and other jquery mobile files

have the image folder of jquery (which download with the ajax loader and white and black icons) in my website folder so I don't know what is the problem.

My code

```
<a href="#index.html" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">back</a>
```

other thing I currently use the last jquery mobile version

Comment: are you sure you have icon pack in the images folder of stylesheet ?

Comment: I add the data-role="buttom" to my code and button works well but problem is the same the icon dont showing in the buttom currenty problem persist now my code is this, I try put the icon black because my website have light color, currently have the simbol in a image folder with my jquery mobile folder files but for example in the image folder that I have in the website folder see that have 4 files 2 of these are 18 pixels icons, other 2 are 36 pixels icons white and black and also ajax page loader

Comment: what is the name of your image.. Is that just arrow-1 or is there some extension laso

Comment: I named arrow-l because I see that is the name that jquery mobile assigned to his icon but write the l letter not 1 one number

Comment: no one has accepting any answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#index.html" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">back</a>
```

you have to add `data-role="button"` in your code.

Comment: is that solved already?